# IBM Watson Unity 3d Visual Recognition SDK: Parsing the classifier output results

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ibm-watson, visual-recognition

I am trying to get the results of the Onclassify call into a usable format. I cannot seem figure out how to return 
classResult.m_class into a usable format such as updating a Text object or to store it in a variable.

Can someone please advise what is a good recommended way to pass the results from classResult.m_class for multiple or single classifiers into variables which I can action on later or pass on to other functions.

```
private void OnClassify(ClassifyTopLevelMultiple classify, string data)
{
    if (classify != null)
    {
        Log.Debug("WebCamRecognition", "images processed: " + classify.images_processed);
        foreach (ClassifyTopLevelSingle image in classify.images)
        {

            Log.Debug("WebCamRecognition", "\tsource_url: " + image.source_url + ", resolved_url: " + image.resolved_url);
            foreach (ClassifyPerClassifier classifier in image.classifiers) {

                Log.Debug ("WebCamRecognition", "\t\tclassifier_id: " + classifier.classifier_id + ", name: " + classifier.name);
                foreach (ClassResult classResult in classifier.classes) {
                    Log.Debug ("WebCamRecognition", "\t\t\tclass: " + classResult.m_class + ", score: " + classResult.score + ", type_hierarchy: " + classResult.type_hierarchy);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Log.Debug("WebCamRecognition", "Classification failed!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ClassifyTopLevelMultiple` object contains an array of `ClassifyTopLevelSingle` objects in the `images` property. Within each of those `ClassifyTopLevelSingle` objects, there is an array of `ClassifyPerClassifier` objects which give you the result per custom classifier. Each `ClassifyPerClassifier` object has a list of `ClassResult` objects which contain the `class` and the `score`.

You can pull out the class and the score for each result for the first item in each array like this:

```
private void OnClassifyGet(ClassifyTopLevelMultiple classify, string data)
{
    string class = classify.images[0].classifiers[0].classes[0].m_class;
    string classScore= classify.images[0].classifiers[0].classes[0].score;
}
```

The example code you posted will iterate through all images, classifiers and classes to list all classes and scores in each `ClassifyTopLevelMultiple` result.

Also it is worth noting that there is an [updated version](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/unity-sdk) of the Watson Unity SDK. If you are just beginning a project it might be worth it to start with the latest SDK version since the latest release is a breaking change from all previous releases.

Comment: thanks Taj ! I wasn't aware there was a new SDK. I Has the documentation been updated ?

Comment: just one thing i noticed taj in the code samples/snippets(https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/unity-sdk/tree/develop/Scripts/Services/VisualRecognition/v3) you are referencing data  but its not declaring the variable  in the call.                                                       private void OnUpdateClassifier(GetClassifiersPerClassifierVerbose classifier)
{
    Log.Debug("ExampleVisualRecognition", "Update classifier result: {0}", data);
}

Comment: Data is a string you can pass any data through. If data is null when you initially make the call, I add the raw json that is returned from the service. It's an easy way to see what the object looks like.

Comment: Taj just to confirm, my project is still using the previous unity SDK. Do i need to update this or will my code function as normal . For the last day or so the platform has indicated I am making too many concurrent http requests and I use the service on the Standard Package. there is no way I did more than 25 000 calls in one day. any advice ?

Comment: In my experience the limit for Visual Recognition is much lower than 25k API calls. This has nothing to do with the SDK. I think all users should update to the latest version of the Unity SDK. You should have minimal changes if you are only using Visual Recognition.

Comment: Thanks Taj. I'll move over to the newer SDK anyways for consistency though I have to say I liked applying the service credentials in the drop down menu. Thanks for the great work on the SDK and for supporting Unity.